# Can't install because I don't have high enough Ruby version, but I do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, activesupport

I'm trying to add a widget to a dashboard. I've cloned the widget to the correct directory and copied files over to the relevant locations. The final thing to do is run this line:

```
bundle install
```

Everything goes well until I get line :

```
Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '5.0.0.1'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

So I've installed that separately:

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 5.0.0.1
Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.0.1
```

But when I try to run "bundle install" I get the same error.

I even checked by ruby version, and its high enough:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it choosing to use a lower version of ruby?

Comment: What's `iruby` exactly?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo somehow. Fixed now.

Comment: try doing `bundle list` to verify that bundler is finding the correct version. You might also try `gem list | grep activesupport`. Sometimes I'll find I have more than one version installed and the wrong one is named first, suggesting that's the one that is being picked up.

Comment: Please add the output of `gem env` to your question, formatted correctly so it's readable. In general `sudo` waves a flag to us that you're doing something you should be wary of doing. We recommend using RVM or rbenv to manage your Ruby/Rubies, and which, whether you're using RVM or rbenv, allows you to not worry about having super-user permissions and the possible concern you'll accidentally overwrite code needed by your system. You're on Mac OS, so `sudo` will change the vendor supplied Ruby, which isn't a great idea. This is covered many times on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using RVM or Rbenv for managing Ruby? If so, you shouldn't use `sudo` to install that gem as it'll be placed in your system Ruby, which usually is lower version.

Comment: I don't use either, I just get permission denied when I don't use sudo.

Comment: You should definitely use one of them. I personally recommend using RVM. It's much easier to manage. Try installing it and then using your bundle with it. Let me know how it goes from there (it should fix your issue)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I finally solved running it as sudo:

```
sudo bundle install
```

Be sure your Gemfile is in the same directory where you are running the command and just in case the Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

In the end you get something like this: 
...

```
-------------------------------------------------
Thank you for installing html-pipeline!
You must bundle Filter gem dependencies.
See html-pipeline README.md for more details.
https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline#dependencies
-------------------------------------------------
```